# delete sql not deleting

Tags: java, sql, mysql, netbeans

I'm trying to delete an event from my table. However I can't seem to get it to work.
My SQL statement is:

```
  public void deleteEvent(String eventName){
    String query = "DELETE FROM `Event` WHERE `eventName` ='"+eventName+"' LIMIT 1";
    db.update(query);
    System.out.println (query);
}
```

Using MySQL db

Comment: what is `db` and what does `update` do, I don't know, but I am sure that if you read this: http://oreilly.com/catalog/javadata/chapter/ch04.html , and write your queries correctly, you will get the desired results.

Comment: hi. db is my database and update should update my query (in essence)

Comment: What do you mean by "db is my database"...how are you abstracting your database with a class?

Comment: Surprised no one has mentioned the obvious SQL injection possibilities / problems with event names containing `'`. Use parameterised queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the following :

```
String query = "DELETE FROM `Event` WHERE `eventName` ='"+eventName+"' LIMIT 1";

        try {
            Connection con = getConnection();
            Statement s = con.createStatement();

            s.execute(query);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

You have to code your `getConnection()` method to return a valid Database Connection.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Statement.executeUpdate](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29) method, since it returns an integer. So after performing this delete query you will also have information if you really deleted any records (in this case you would expect this method to return 1, since you are using LIMIT=1). I would also suggest closing Statement as soon as you don't need it, here is skeleton implementation:

```
private void performDelete(Connection conn, String deleteQuery, int expectedResult) throws SQLException {
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    int result = -1;
    try {
        result = stmt.executeUpdate(deleteQuery);
        if(result != expectedResult) {
            //Here you can check the result. Perhaps you don't need this part
            throw new IllegalStateException("Develete query did not return expected value");
        }
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        //Good practice if you use loggers - log it here and rethrow upper.
        //Or perhaps you don't need to bother in upper layer if the operation
        //was successful or not - in such case, just log it and thats it.
        throw e;
    } finally {
        //This should be always used in conjunction with ReultSets.
        //It is not 100% necessary here, but it will not hurt
        stmt.close();
    }
}
```