# When is ResultSet closed?

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to know if ResultSet can be closed if I didn't close it ? I have a ResultSet is closed exception but I am sure I didn't close the ResultSet anywhere .
What I do exactly is that I use the ResultSet to perform a SELECT query then I use the same ResultSet because it's called by this method :

```
public Object getValueAt( int row, int column )
        throws IllegalStateException {
    // ensure database connection is available
    if ( !dbConnection.isConnectedToDatabase() )
        throw new IllegalStateException( "Not Connected to Database" );

    // obtain a value at specified ResultSet row and column

    try {
        getResultSet().absolute( row + 1 );
        return getResultSet().getObject( column + 1 );
    } // end try
    catch ( SQLException sqlException ) {
        System.out.println("Exception from here dude");
        sqlException.printStackTrace();
    } // end catch

    return ""; // if problems, return empty string object
} // end method getValueAt
```

So , another question : Is there a way to ensure the ResultSet is opened ?

Third question : Maybe the problem because I never close ResultSets .

What's the point of closing ResultSet ?

Edit : That's how statement is being created inside the constructor of a class called DBConnection:

```
Class.forName(driver);
        // connect to database
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

        // create Statement to query database
        statement = connection.createStatement(
     ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
     ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY );

        //connection ok
        connectedToDatabase=true;
```

ResultSet is created later whenever I want to execute a statement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Directly from [the docs on ResultSet.close()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#close()):

> Releases this ResultSet object's database and JDBC resources immediately instead of waiting for this to happen when it is automatically closed.
>
> ...
>
> Note: A ResultSet object is automatically closed by the Statement object that generated it when that Statement object is closed, re-executed, or is used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of multiple results.

So, if you closed the Statement that generated your ResultSet is closed, you get that exception.

Another question's answer: you shouldn't read results from a ResultSet like that. Perform the select an read all the data you need from the ResultSet at once, close the connection and then later you can read the fetched data as much as you want. You really shouldn't have an external resource/class calling your `getValueAt` method, which you expect to still be connected to the database. Connection may be terminated for many other reasons, so that's not the way to go.

Third answer: answered above.

Last answer: releasing resources explicitly, without waiting for it to be closed when Statement is.

Comment: Those are 2 different operations actually .. I am using one connection , so I am using one statement and many resultsets . Is that the problem ?

Comment: @Ahmed If you read the 'Note' from the docs section I pasted above, it says that a ResultSet is closed if it is re-executed or the next result os multiple results is retrieved. So, whatever is your approach for this, only the last ResultSet is valid, and all the others are closed. As I said, retrieve all the results, store them somewhere, and then read them as you like.

Comment: How do I use your approach and ResultSetTableModel together ? ResultSetTableModel deals with the resultset directly.

Comment: @Ahmed `Raccoon.GUI.ResultSetTableModel`? I never heard of this class before, let alone use it. In this case, you might make the search, display the reults then close it. Otherwise, read each row of data into an array or special object, put each one in a list/array, close the `ResultSet` and then use this list/array to read and display data, without worrying about closed connections or anything, like I said before.

Answer (score -1):

In case you have closed any of the following, your ResultSet will be closed automatically:

1. Statement object.
2. Connection object.

I am strongly suspecting the connection is being closed. It is a natural tendency to close the database connection once the query is run. While it is a good practice, but may be you are closing the connection even before you have used the ResultSet object inside your TableModel class.

Comment: No . maybe because I am using one statement instance for all my queries ?

Answer (score -1):

I always close Connections, ResultSets and Statements in finally {} block. In such case I don't have this problem, since this block is always executed (Well, not always, but here it fits). Please refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983984/delete-sql-not-deleting/4984208#4984208), I placed skeleton implementation that might be interesting for you.